# Tracial states and the GNS construction

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If a $C^*$-algebra $A$ has a tracial state $\tau$, can we construct a nonzero representation $\pi: A\rightarrow B(H_{\tau})$ such that $\pi(ab)=\pi(ba),\forall a,b \in A$ through the GNS construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about GNS. Many C$^*$-algebras lack commutative representations. For instance, if $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$ with $n\geq2$, then any representation is either zero or unitarily equivalent to the identity representation.

Or, if $A=B(H)$, the any representation is either (unitarily equivalent to) the identity, or the quotient map onto the Calkin algebra.

Comment: Not in the examples I gave you, unless  $a_0$ is in the centre.

Comment: If the center of A is zero,can we construct an ideal I such that the center of A/I is nonzero?

Comment: Not if $A $ is simple.

Comment: What about the case when $A$ is non-simple?

Comment: @mathrookie $A=K(H)\oplus K(H)$. The only ideals are $K(H)\oplus\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\oplus K(H)$

Comment: @Aweygan，Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $A=M_n(\mathbb C)$ and the standard tracial state $\tau$.  Then the GNS representation $\pi:A\to B(H_\tau)$ is injective (an easy exercise), and thus commutators aren't mapped to zero.